# onSave- / onRestoreInstanceState not working

Tags: java, android, android-savedstate

The situation is that I want to create an app, which should be able to create a new TextView in a LinearLayout everytime a button is clicked. A text from and EditText ist assigned to said TextView. I managed to pull this off. However I've been struggling on how to save all of the created TextViews, once the app is closed and started up again. I tried using OnSaveInstanceState and OnRestoreInstance state to save an Array, to which I save every text that is displayed on a TextView. After restored I would check the size of the arraylist and create for a TextView for every value in the arraylist, so that all is restored. However, it doesn't work. I know, that the names are saved to the arraylist, however, nothing is restored, when I restart the app. Here's my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<String>  SubjectArray = new ArrayList<String>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button savebtn = findViewById(R.id.MAINsave);
        EditText newname = findViewById(R.id.newname);
        CheckBox promo = findViewById(R.id.MAINpromo);
        LinearLayout linearlayout = findViewById(R.id.MAINln);


        savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                newsub();
            }
        });


    }

    private void newsub(){



        EditText newname = findViewById(R.id.newname);
        CheckBox promo = findViewById(R.id.MAINpromo);
        LinearLayout MAINln = findViewById(R.id.MAINln);


        SubjectArray.add(newname.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Added To Array", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
        Params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);

        TextView newsubject = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        newsubject.setText(newname.getText().toString());
        newsubject.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
        newsubject.setBackgroundColor(GRAY);
        newsubject.setLayoutParams(Params);

        MAINln.addView(newsubject);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        SubjectArray = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("KEY_SUBJECTARRAY");
        LinearLayout MAINln = findViewById(R.id.MAINln);


        int subjectcount = SubjectArray.size();

        for (int i = 0; i <= subjectcount; i++) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams Params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
            Params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 10);

            TextView restoredsubject = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            restoredsubject.setText(SubjectArray.get(i));
            restoredsubject.setGravity(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            restoredsubject.setBackgroundColor(GRAY);
            restoredsubject.setLayoutParams(Params);

            MAINln.addView(restoredsubject);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putStringArrayList("KEY_SUBJECTARRAY", SubjectArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Confirm the size of the restored array

Comment: try that on restore in onCreate

Answer (score 0):

you can manage a local database table and every time you are adding the new TextView just insert the Text of that TextView in the table . When you start your application first check the data of that table, if available then get the data in a list .
After getting list 
Apply a loop on list size 
Add a new textview inside body of loop
Set the current indexed text in Added TextView inside the loop.

you can clear table also when you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "restart the app" you mean, a fresh start?

The `savedInstanceState` is not made for this. You save the state for moments when the instance of your Activity gets recreated.

As an example, when the user is turning the phone to landscape formatting. Then a `onConfigurationChanged` event happens (depends on how you set up your activity in the manifest) and `onCreate` gets called with the Bundle you saved in `onSaveInstanceState`.

To persist your state over app sessions, best approach is either saving it in the `SharedPreferences` (and loading them in `onCreate` of your MainActivity oder Application class) or to persist them in a database table.

Answer (score 0):

The `onRestoreInstanceState` not made this purpose. It has a different purpose like, if your activity was previously destroyed and you going to recreate the activity again, at this you could be able to retrieve the saved data. For more details click [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#restore-activity-ui-state-using-saved-instance-state).

In this case, recommend using preferences or lightWeight persistence libraries like [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). So you could retrieve the details any point the app until clear the data of the app.